# Putting gender with 3 options in an element of an array

Tags: c#

There is a class of passenger with int age, string gender, string major. I make an array of this class. My problem is I don't know how to declare and assign gender here. Because gender should be with 3 options that user chooses: 1.male 2.female 3.prefer-not-to-say for example, by switch I guess and maybe a method for gender??

After this, I need to be able to count all passengers with same gender and show it on screen.

```
public void Add_Passengers ()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (passengers[i] != null)
    {
        i++;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("How old is the passenger?");
    int age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    Console.WriteLine("Choose the gender:");
    // code for options for gender... 
    
    Console.WriteLine("Write the major now:");
    string Major = Console.ReadLine();
    
    passengers[i] = new Passenger(age, gender, Major);
    Console.WriteLine("Passenger number {0}: Age: {1}, Gender: {2}, Major: {3}" i, age, gender, Major);
}

public class Passenger
{
    public int age;
    public string gender;
    public string major;

    public Passenger(int Age, string Gender, string Major)
    {
        age = Age;
        gender = Gender;
        major = Major;
    }

    public int Get_Age ()
    {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you learn about `enum`s?

Comment: just read a little about it..

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go:

```
public class Passenger
{
    public Passenger(int age, Gender gender, string major)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        this.Gender = gender;
        this.Major = major;
    }

    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; private set; }
    public string Major { get; private set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    PreferNotToSay,
    Male,
    Female,
}
```

I have also updated your class to follow more common C# coding standards.